# Parsing 2 head json and grouping using php

Tags: php, json

I have a json like this.But not getting an idea how to parse and display inside a select box using php under heading of name.Basically It has 2 
name Customers,Lead.So each values will be displaying under these head.
First step is

```
$data = json_decode($json);
```

and a foreach will provide results ? but how to show head names ?

```
{
    "status": {
        "message": "success",
        "code": 200
    },
    "clients": [
        {
            "values": [
                {
                    "Code": "rdf",
                    "name": "Adfgf"
                },
                {
                    "Code": "fg",
                    "name": "fg"
                }
            ],
            "name": "Customers"
        },
        {
            "values": [
                {
                    "Code": "fgf",
                    "name": "fgdf"
                },
                {
                    "Code": "api",
                    "name": "fgfdgd"
                },
                {
                    "Code": "fgbb",
                    "name": "mnn"
                },
                {
                    "Code": "acy",
                    "name": "System"
                }
            ],
            "name": "Lead"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: its getting from  webservice,Its returns like this when I check with REST client in chrome plugin

Comment: You'll need to echo the raw JSON and post it.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I have updated valid code

Comment: first step is $data = json_decode($json); then a foreach ?

Comment: What should the select box look like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65229/discussion-between-aniltc-and-abracadaver).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the code
http://codepad.org/vLhzs6kJ#output

```
$string = '{
    "status": {
        "message": "success",
        "code": 200
    },
    "clients": [
        {
            "values": [
                {
                    "Code": "rdf",
                    "name": "first"
                },
                {
                    "Code": "fg",
                    "name": "second"
                }
            ],
            "name": "Customers"
        },
        {
            "values": [
                {
                    "Code": "fgf",
                    "name": "third"
                },
                {
                    "Code": "api",
                    "name": "4th"
                },
                {
                    "Code": "fgbb",
                    "name": "5th"
                },
                {
                    "Code": "acy",
                    "name": "last"
                }
            ],
            "name": "Lead"
        }
    ]
}';

$data = json_decode($string,true);

echo "<Select>";
foreach ($data['clients'] as $c) {

    $gp =$c['name'];
   echo "<optgroup label=$gp>";

    # calling the function on the values data       
    recurse($c['values']);
   echo  '</optgroup>';

}

function recurse($arr, $level = 0){
    # we have a numerically-indexed array. go through each item:
    foreach ($arr as $n) {
        # print out the item ID and the item name
        echo '<option value="' . $n['Code'] . '">' 
        . $n['name']
        . '</option>'
        ;

    }

}
 echo "</Select>";
```